# Where to find a task I made?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task-manager

I made a task in task manager but I did not schedule it.  Instead I made a shortcut to it.  I want to edit the original task, but I cannot find it.  How do I find it so I can edit it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go back to Task Scheduler, and click on the Task Scheduler Library node.

There's a list of tasks in the center panel.

However, if you had expanded the tree and had selected a non-root node (eg you were in the Games node), then the Task appears when you select that node in the tree.

You might have to go through each node to find it.